# Ajax request in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

Need help in understanding on how we can make Ajax request in LWC. I tried importing jquery and use $ajax function but had some issues in loading. Is there a better way ?
Problem is i have more than 6mb of data to handle and render in LWC.

Thanks everyone who will share their experience and knowledge.

Comment: Can you add more context and be more specific? else it might get closed.

Comment: I want to make a get request in lightning webcomponent js. Tried it using importing jquery and calling ajax. Is there a another standard way of doing in LWC ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if you want the standard way to do this you can use XHR or Fetch.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

You want to be mindful of how often you will fire the request in your component. From the sounds of it you are creating a loader for a large dataset.

Comment: Thanks. Already did a standard way. But looking forward to a better approach in lwc
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url='https://abc.com?no_cache=false';
        Http.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'XXXXX');
        Http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        Http.open("GET", url);
        Http.send();
        Http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
            console.log(Http.responseText)
        }

Comment: yes, its more than 12mb that is why i want to handle in js and render it on a data visualization library

Comment: Hi Kevin, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [answer]. Please use statements rather than asking questions when posting an `Answer`.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the core issue you are having, you mentioned that the jQuery $ajax function had issues. What were the issues with $ajax? Was the XHR request not working as well?